# Where is the best place to put one-time and every-time code in GAE/Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am new to Google App Engine and Python. I am having trouble understanding some basic questions about Python apps running on Google App Engine.

If I want code to execute:

1. On every incoming request, where should I put it? We are capturing session information about what pages are viewed when by whom, and what did they do, etc.
2. Only once when the app is started, where should I put it? I need to initialize a number of application/system variables that are used in many places in the application.  Where is the best place to put the code to do this?

If anyone can point me to any documentation or tutorials that explain what the best architecture practices are for GAE/Python apps, without the basics of programming stuff, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

## Question Number 1:

Some web frameworks (Django, KAY, etc) have a concept of Middleware. You can create your own middleware that will execute on every request and handle this sort of information
(see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)

## Question Number 2:

Warmup requests (see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests)

Though since warmup requests are not guaranteed to run, you can put a global variable to let the instance know if it was "initialized" and check that variable on every page load (this will be cheap since the variable will live in memory and exist between requests). If it is not set, then run through your "warmup" as needed.

Comment: Regarding the middleware idea, I have tried to avoid Django and similar because I am staying away from SQL and the nonSQL solutions do not look as though they have been very stable.  I would prefer using such a solution if it had a following as strong as say Drupal, but that does not appear to be the case.  As a result I am rolling my own framework if you would.  Do you know of anywhere that describes how to build one's own middleware independent of Django and the like?

Comment: Regarding the warmup, when you say every page load, do you mean to put something at the top of main.py or can one put at the top of every .py file or in the basehandler function of a .py file?  I do not really understand when logic in different parts of these files actually executs.

Comment: I would try and base your framework off of something current and working. Django can work with app engine quite nicely, and frameworks like KAY (which i've build a production app on) have a lot of strong features that you can leverage. Maybe you can just fork one of the existing frameworks and build your own features on top of them? You can throw the check for a warmup in a middleware class or on top of every .py file as you described though the latter is a messy way of doing it.

Comment: Middleware is a WSGI concept, and pretty much every Python framework uses WSGI. There are plenty of well supported frameworks on App Engine; rolling your own is almost certainly a waste of your time.

Comment: Perhaps my greatest frustration with Google App Engine / Python is that  there does not seem to be anyplace one can go to find a list of the various modules by type with ratings and reviews.  When I decided to try to use Django nonrel, the first thing I find is a goodbye notice from the key supporters.  I am open, but I am using GAE and no SQL, can anyone give me some examples of a framework for that environment with enough of a critical mass of followers to ensure survival for at least the next 5 or so years?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You are not forced to use Django nonrel with AppEngine if you don't need to. Does the framework you want to use require an ORM? There may be limitations to using an ORM with AppEngine's datastore, for instance, using tasklets and Futures with the NDB API. Django is probably your best bet in terms of maturity and longevity. Other frameworks exist but its hard to gauge the user base. You can try using some of these frameworks and helping the project yourself. You can also make the framework your own if the maintainers leave.